# TypeError: superCtor is undefined (inherits inherits_browser.js)

Tags: javascript, ibm-watson, angular9

After migrating the project to angular 9 following error started occurring:
[superCtor is undefined](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MsyBh.png)

which seems to be referring to inherits_browser.js that is coming from the npm module readable-blob-stream. Error seems to be coming from the following line in index.js of the module:
[index.js of readable-blob-stream](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EF8pT.png). Versions being used are as follows:
[versions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HPbGu.png). watson-speech version of 0.38.0 is being used.

I've tried reinstalling node_modules which doesn't resolve the issue.
I've also tested the compatibility of watson-speech package with angular9 by a standalone project (Seems to be compatible). Could anyone suggest why the error might be caused in the migrated project?

Has anyone experienced this before and could let me know the scenarios this can occur in?

Comment: At a cursory glance that looks like there's some sort of required shim or something missing. Maybe something missing dependency from your package.json. Post the contents of that perhaps too.

Comment: https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/node-sdk/issues/843

Comment: UPDATE: I resolved the issue by modifying the line 'var Stream = require('stream');' in index.js of readable-blob-stream to 'var Stream = require('readable-stream');'. This https://github.com/nodejs/readable-stream/issues/237 was helpful in the issue resolution.

Comment: Cool. Glad that worked for you.

Answer (score 2):

From github https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/11940#issuecomment-723153728

I had a similar issue with react after upgrading webpack 4->5. It was the same console error. Maybe this will help for the angular folk in some way.

In my webpack config I added:

```
 resolve: {
    alias: { "stream": require.resolve("stream-browserify") }
 }
```

Comment: This worked, but I had to install `stream-browserify` to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

Copied from RAKSHA SHENOY's comment:

I resolved the issue by modifying the line

```
var Stream = require('stream');
```

in index.js of node_modules/readable-blob-stream to

```
var Stream = require('readable-stream');
```

If someone has a cleaner solution that does not require fiddling around in node_modules, please share it.